# Deleted stats images from webalizer by accident

Tags: directadmin, webalizer

Good evening

I just did something stupid,

I am hosting my website somewhere and they have DirectAdmin and they use webalizer to generate stats.
So i was playing around in DirectAdmin and saw a option to make stats public. And did that to watch and play around. But then i decided to "Disable" the public stats. And the way i thought to dot that was to go to my ftp server and delete the folder /stats it created when i made it public. So i deleted the file /stats but now i have a bunch of broken image links in DirectAdmin and can't see the stats anymore. Is there a way to generate new ones?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a help-desk support question for your host?

Comment: @MikeB It is technically not a programming question. But the help-desk from my host did not help, no answer from them since a couple days. So i thought i try it here maybe somebody knows.